# Android,sqlite,how to insert date record automatic?

Tags: android, sqlite

```
 -_id   -lesson_id  -start_time -SUMDUEDURATION -COUNTDUEDURATION   -INTERVAL
    -105    -1  -2013-10-16 07:26:52.000    -92736  -9  -301418
    -108    -1  -2013-10-18 07:03:52.000    -164282 -3  -555779
    -116    -1  -2013-10-21 11:49:44.000    -1455866-7  -3533900
    -128    -1  -2013-10-22 11:12:55.000    -53795  -12 -108334
    -132    -1  -2013-10-30 03:27:46.000    -2036   -1  -663295276
```

Here are records in user action table,only few days of the month,are there any event schedule like MySQL to insert the other dates automatic.

i use this to cross a date table,but not good enough:

```
select _id,lesson_id,start_time, ifnull(sum,0) as SUMDUEDURATION, ifnull(COUNT,0) as COUNTDUEDURATION, ifnull(interval, 0) as INTERVAL
from dates left join (
SELECT month,_id, lesson_id, sum(duration) as sum,count(_id) as count,interval, 
start_time,end_time,
max(date(" + START_TIME + ", 'weekday 0', '-7 day')) as WeekStart,
max(date(" + START_TIME + ", 'weekday 0', '-1 day')) as WeekEnd
FROM user_action where lesson_id = 1 group by month )  monthdate  using(month)  
where strftime('%Y%m',date) = strftime('%Y%m','now')
```

Comment: IMO, you'd better check and fill database whenever your application is started. SQLite is serverless, data is only accessed/write when your application uses it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) an use it to add row when you only want (e.g. on boot completed, once per week, etc., etc.).

[Here you have good tutorial,](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) how to create Service in Android OS.

Read also more about [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to start your Service in specific schedule.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
// Start every 30 seconds
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000, pintent);
```

Comment: Are there any SQL statements to do this job?

Comment: @user2571625 Add SQL statements in your Service code. Here you have good tutorial about [SQLite](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) databases on Android

Comment: thanks,i use this to cross a date table,but not good enough:
select _id,lesson_id,start_time, ifnull(sum,0) as SUMDUEDURATION, ifnull(COUNT,0) as COUNTDUEDURATION, ifnull(interval, 0) as INTERVAL
from dates left join (
SELECT month,_id, lesson_id, sum(duration) as sum,count(_id) as count,interval, 
start_time,end_time,
max(date(" + START_TIME + ", 'weekday 0', '-7 day')) as WeekStart,
max(date(" + START_TIME + ", 'weekday 0', '-1 day')) as WeekEnd
FROM user_action where lesson_id = 1 group by month )  monthdate  using(month)  where strftime('%Y%m',date) = strftime('%Y%m','now')

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, this can only be achieved with a timestamp, not with datetime.
Here is a short example, how you can add a default Timestamp.

```
create table test (str varchar(32), ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

edit: never mind, i somehow thought you want that for mysql.

Comment: but I want it work even no new record insert.